# Verifying all address locations of memory

Tags: constraints, verilog, system-verilog, verify

If I have a (address 32 bits wide) for a dual port RAM, what verification strategies are used to verify the entire memory space? Of course, we heavily rely on randomization of the address. But that does not ensure ALL address locations are verified.

What verification strategies are adopted to ensure all address locations of a large memory is thoroughly verified?

Comment: You can't verify "all address locations" without testing all address locations. If you don't have the time or resources to do that, randomisation *may* be helpful, but only if it is constrained to exercise the interesting parts of an otherwise unmangeable problem space. Otherwise, it's useless. Your options are (1) to use normal software algorithms for testing large memories (walking ones, etc), and (2) talk to the hardware people, find out how the memory works, and identify corner cases to test yourself.